# PHP Activerecord Model Count

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Get result as below

```
$result = MyModel::find_by_id($id);
```

How can I count the result number directly?

Comment: you can use `count()` for that.

Comment: How? like this count($result)?

Comment: `$count  = count($result_array)` this way

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('emp');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0){
  return count($query->result());//here you can get count
  //return count($query->result_array());//here you can get count
}
```

OR

```
echo $this->db->count_all('emp');
```

OR

```
$this->db->like('fname', 'eve');
$this->db->from('emp');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple solution

```
$count = $this->db->get('table')->num_rows();
```

But if you want data as well then

```
$data = $this->db->get('table')->result();
$count = count($data);
```